# Delete data from other paths in folder resources

Tags: anylogic

I saved databases on my desktop and delete them but I dont know that I get a problem to copy my model to another laptop. So for now they are in my anylogic folder resources. I cant delete the databases. The delete buttons are grey.
Is there a way to delete the connected data? I dont have the paths on my desktop anymore.

[image: folder]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [help](https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2Fconnectivity%2FResources.html&resultof=%22%72%65%73%6F%75%72%63%65%73%22%20%22%72%65%73%6F%75%72%63%22%20) on what the colors mean. Gray means that the file is still in the model folder but not actually used by the model. So no problem (but obviously you cannot delete it here as it must be deleted in the model folder itself by your OS)